# How can I make my class instances usable as dict keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

```
class A():
   def __init__(self, data=''):
       self.data = data  

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.data)

d = {}  
elem = A()  
d[elem] = 'abc'  

elem2 = A()
print d[elem2]    # KeyError  
# actually elem2! was used not elem
```

how can I implement this without error?

I tried to get `d[elem2]` (not `elem`) with another instance of A() BUT with the same content.

Comment: What error (message)? And does it really only occur when you access an element, rather than setting it? Do you really (as in the example) use the same instance in both lines, or does it amount to `d[A()] = ...; print d[A()]`?

Comment: Yes, only when getting, not setting. Edited: KeyError.

Comment: @Sergey: You will have to tell us more about class `A`.  Did you overwrite any special methods?  When posting error messages, please give the **full** error message, including the traceback.

Comment: defined __init__ and __str__ as I wrote above

Comment: The updated code runs without error for me.

Comment: sorry everyone, edited the question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer is yes, you need to redefine `__hash__()` and `__eq__()`:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self, data=''):
...     self.data = data
...   def __eq__(self, another):
...     return hasattr(another, 'data') and self.data == another.data
...   def __hash__(self):
...     return hash(self.data)
... 
>>> a1, a2, a3 = A('foo'), A('foo'), A('bar')
>>> d = {a1: 'foo'}
>>> d[a1]
'foo'
>>> d[a2]
'foo'
>>> d[a3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
KeyError: __main__.A object at 0x927d0>
```

As explained in another comment default implementation of `__hash__` is just simple identity, so if you want to make it more sophisticated, you need to define it explicitly.

Comment: You also need to implement `__eq__`, or strange things happen (at least in Python 2.7), I've tested it for you...

Answer (score 7):

What you did should work, as long as you don't override the `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` methods.  It will use object identity as equality.  If you want a different notion of equality, you can override the `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` methods of your class.

Comment: a small example of __hash__ and __eq__ would be great

Comment: What defines identity for the object? That is, what fields, if you changed them, would cause the object to represent another entity? Suppose the object represents a person and contains a unique identifier like SSN. Then you might decide that if two objects' `ssn` attribute is the same, then they are equal even if their names are different (since people can change their names). You would then write `__eq__()` to compare only `self.ssn` and `__hash__()` to return `hash(self.ssn)`. Any number of fields might be considered, depending on what the objects represent.