# Using object as key in dictionary in Python - Hash function

Tags: python, object, dictionary, key

I am trying to use an object as the key value to a dictionary in Python. I follow the recommendations from some other posts that we need to implement 2 functions: `__hash__` and `__eq__`

And with that, I am expecting the following to work but it didn't.

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self.name))
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self.name) == str(other,name)
        
        
def TestMethod():
    test_Dict = {}
    
    obj = Test('abc')
    test_Dict[obj] = obj
    
    print "%s" %(test_Dict[hash(str('abc'))].name)       # expecting this to print "abc"
```

But it is giving me a key error message:

```
KeyError: 1453079729188098211
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `return str(self.name) == str(other,name)` apparently has a bug in `str(other,name)` I don't understand how this is not raised. Even if it's `str(other.name)` it still wouldn't work because `hash(str('abc'))` doesn't have `.name` attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elements of a mapping are *not* accessed by their hash, even though their hash is used to place them within the mapping. You *must* use the same value when indexing both for storage and for retrieval.

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to redefine `hash` and `eq` to use an object as dictionary key.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

test_Dict = {}

obj = Test('abc')
test_Dict[obj] = obj

print test_Dict[obj].name
```

This works fine and print `abc`.
As explained by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams you don't use the hash of the object but the object itself as key to access the dictionary value.

---

The examples you found like [python: my classes as dict keys. how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221236/python-my-classes-as-dict-keys-how?rq=1) or [Object of custom type as dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901815/object-as-a-dictionary-key?rq=1) redefine `hash` and `eq` for specific purpose.

For example consider these two objects `obj = Test('abc')` and `obj2 = Test('abc')`.

```
test_Dict[obj] = obj
print test_Dict[obj2].name
```

This will throw a `KeyError` exception because obj and obj2 are not the same object.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self.name))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self.name) == str(other.name)

obj = Test('abc')
obj2 = Test('abc')       

test_Dict[obj] = obj
print test_Dict[obj2].name
```

This print `abc`. `obj` and `obj2` are still different objects but now they have the same hash and are evaluated as equals when compared.

Answer (score 2):

## Error Explanation

Given the code provided in the post, I don't actually see how you get the KeyError because you should be receiving an AttributeError (assuming the `str(other,name)` was a typo meant to be `str(other.name)`). The AttributeError comes from the `__eq__` method when comparing the name of self against the name of other because your key during lookup, `hash(str('abc'))`, is an int/long, not a `Test` object.

When looking up a key in a dict, the first operation performed is getting the hash of the key using the key's `__hash__` method. Second, if a value for this hash exists in the dict, the `__eq__` method of the key is called to compare the key against whatever value was found. This is to make sure that in the event objects with the same hash are stored in the dict (through open addressing), the correct object is retrieved. On average this lookup is still O(1).

Looking at this one step at a time, the hash of `hash(str('abc'))` and `obj` are the same. In `Test`, you define `__hash__` as the hash of a string. When performing lookup with `test_Dict[hash(str('abc'))]`, you are actually looking up the hash of a hash, but this is still fine since the hash of an int is itself in python.

When comparing these two values according to your defined `__eq__` method, you compare the names of the objects, but the value you are comparing against is an int (`hash(str('abc'))`), which does not have a `name` property, so the AttributeError is raised.

## Solution

Firstly, you do not need to (and should not) call `hash()` when performing the actual dict lookup since this key is also passed as the second argument to your `__eq__` method. So

```
test_Dict[hash(str('abc'))].name
```

should become

```
test_Dict[str('abc')].name
```

or just

```
test_Dict['abc'].name
```

since calling `str()` on a string literal doesn't make much sense.

Secondly, you will need to edit your `__eq__` method such that it takes into account the type of the `other` object you are comparing against. You have different options for this depending on what else will be stored in the same dict with your `Test` instances as keys.

- If you plan to store your `Test` instances in a dictionary only with other `Test`s (or any objects that have a `name` property), then you can keep what you currently have

  ```
  def __eq__(self, other):
      return str(self.name) == str(other.name)
  ```

  since you guarantee that every other key you are comparing against in the dict is of type `Test` and has a `name`.
- If you plan to mix your `Test` instances in a dictionary with just strings, you will have to check if the object you compare against is a string or not since strings do not have a `name` property in python.

  ```
  def __eq__(self, other):
      if isinstance(other, str):
          return str(self.name) == other
      return str(self.name) == str(other.name)
  ```
- If you plan to use as keys a mix of `Test`s and any other types of objects, you will need to check if the `other` object has a `name` to compare against.

  ```
  def __eq__(self, other):
      if hasattr(other, "name"):
          return str(self.name) == str(other.name)
      return self.name == other  # Or some other logic since here since I don't know how you want to handle other types of classes.
  ```

I'm not much of a fan of the last 2 since you kind of go against duck typing in python with those, but there are always exceptions in life.