# check if a class instance (which serves as a dict key in this case), has all the same attributes as another instance of the same class

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, key, instance

I would like to create a custom class and use an instance of the class as a key of a dict.

I would then like to create other instances of that class, and check if all the attributes are the same as the instance I added as a key to that dict.

I think I am failing at this because when I try to use:

```
if my_object in my_dict:
    my_dict[my_object]['another_dict_key'].append('Found you!')
else:
    my_dict.update(my_object:{'another_dict_key':[]})
```

I suppose it never makes it inside the if statement because my_object will never match as the 'my_object' instance that's already a dict key because they are not the exact same instance - even though they have identical attributes -

I read a bit in other posts about this and the **hash** and **eq** stuff but i am still confused.  I feel like maybe there is a simple way to do this, or else I can try a whole other approach altogether.  But wanted to ask.

this is a more full look at the code, the snippet i pasted above was just to sort of isolate the problem, here is a more in depth look at it i guess, if this helps, by the way:

```
master_dict = {}
i = 0
for order in orders:

    normalized_structure = Normalized_Structure(order)
    if normalized_structure in master_dict:
        if 'ORD_INSTRUCTIONS' in master_dict[normalized_structure]:
            master_dict[normalized_structure]['ORD_INSTRUCTIONS'].append(Normalized_Order_Instructions(order))
        else:
            master_dict[normalized_structure]['ORD_INSTRUCTIONS'] = Normalized_Order_Instructions(order)
    else:
        master_dict.update({normalized_structure:{'STRUCTURE_ID':i, 'ORD_INSTRUCTIONS':[]}})
        master_dict[normalized_structure]['ORD_INSTRUCTIONS'].append(Normalized_Order_Instructions())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: my classes as dict keys. how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221236/python-my-classes-as-dict-keys-how)

Comment: Hi Steven, I looked at that but am not sure how to do this without setting up that hash / eq painstakingly listing every single attribute.  Is there a shortcut to make that more reasonable for a class with 20 attributes?

Comment: I guess you could do `def __eq__(self, other): return all(v == getattr(other, k) for k, v in vars(self).items())` and something similar for the hash, look up how to do custom hash implementations. You will probably only need something simple though.

Comment: when you say a similar/simple hash, for example maybe even return 0 like in this answer?  is there a slick one liner like the one you were kind enough to write above that would work in hash ?  thanks- i am new to this ...stackoverflow.com/questions/4005318/how-to-implement-a-good-hash-function-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's generally best to write out and comapre each attrbute but with 20 attributes you may want a more flexible and simple approach. So for the equality check you could have

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, type(self)) and all(v == getattr(other, k)
                                                 for k, v in vars(self).items())
```

As for hashing it depends on which approach you want to take.

```
def __hash__(self):
    result = 1
    for k, v in sorted(vars(self).items()):
        result = 31 * result + hash(v) # chosen prime is 31
    return result
```

Or you can create a tuple of each value and hash that.

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(tuple(v for k, v in sorted(vars(self).items())))
```

**Update:**

If some of your attributes are unhashable then you can ignore them like so.

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(tuple(v for k, v in sorted(vars(self).items())
                      if getattr(v, '__hash__') is not None))
```

Otherwise take the first approach and handle how they get hashed in the loop.

Comment: thank you very much.  testing now.  i will have to skip a couple of the vars in self.items() which are dicts bc they throw the unhashable error.  but i know what those are called ahead of time and can just skip them explicitly i guess.  testing now..

Comment: Updated answer for unhashable values.

Comment: I have to test more thoroughly (maybe tomorrow), but for now after light testing your solutions seem effective and your explanations/providing options is appreciated very much.