# in python Class object is immutable object ,but it can be modify,why?

Tags: python, class, object

I am not familiar whih python.I found **class object** and **instance object** can be dictionary's key recently.So i assume class object and instance is mutable object.As we all kown,dictionary's key must be immutable object and like tuple must contains immutable object.in other words,If use a tuple as a dictionary's key.It can't contains list object,ect. But class object can ,class object could modify it's attribute.it confused me for a long time.Please lighten me.And i am not understand class namespace concept ,    instance namespace and the relationship with each other.  Could you explain this for me? Thanks in advance. The following is my testing

```
class Student(object):
   name='tests'
   pass

dic={Student:'test'} #not error
print(id(Student))
Student.name = 'modified'
print(id(Student))
```

Comment: the result is 38964680
38964680

Comment: consider a tuple `t = (‘abc’, [1, 2, 3])`

The above tuple t contains elements of different data types, the first one is an immutable string and the second one is a mutable list.The tuple itself isn’t mutable . i.e. it doesn’t have any methods for changing its contents. Likewise, the string is immutable because strings don’t have any mutating methods. But the list object does have mutating methods, so it can be changed. This is a subtle point, but nonetheless important: the “value” of an immutable object can’t change, but it’s constituent objects can.
refer goo.gl/pRHJm7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: my classes as dict keys. how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221236/python-my-classes-as-dict-keys-how)

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful here.  You're mixing 2 separate (but closely related) concepts.

The first concept is **immutability**.  Immutable objects cannot change once you've created them.

The second concept is **hashability** -- The ability to construct a consistent integer value from an object that does not change over it's lifetime and to define a consistent equality function<sup>1</sup>.  Note, these constraints are *very* important (as we'll see).

The latter concept determines what can be used as a dictionary key (or set item).  By default, class instances have a well defined equality function (two objects are equal iff they have the same `id()`).  Class instances also have an integer value that does not change over their lifetime (their `id()`).  Because the `id()` is also exposed as the `hash()` return value, instances of classes (and, classes themselves which are instances of `type`) are hashable by default.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

f1 = Foo(1)
f2 = Foo(1)

d = {
    f1: 1,
    f2: 2,
}
```

Here we have 2 separate `Foo` instances in our dictionary.  Even though they're the *same*, they aren't equal and they have different hash values.

```
f1 == f2  # False -- They do not have the same id()
hash(f1) == hash(f2)  # False.  By default, the hash() is the id()
```

Ok, but not all things are hashable -- e.g. `list` and `set` instances aren't hashable.  At some point, reference equality isn't so useful anymore.  e.g. I write:

```
d = {[1, 2, 3]: 6}
print(d[1, 2, 3])
```

and I get a `KeyError`.  Why?  Because my two lists aren't the same list -- They just happen to have the same values.  In other words, they equal, but they don't have reference equality.  Now that just starts to get really confusing.  To avoid all that confusion, the python devs have just decided to *not* expose the list's `id()` to the list's `hash()`.  Instead, they raise a `TypeError` with a (hopefully) more helpful error message.

```
hash([])  # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Note that equality *is* overridden to do the natural thing rather than compare by `id()`:

```
l1 = [1]
l2 = [1]
l1 == l2  # True.  Nice.
```

Alright, so far we've basically said that to put something in a dictionary, we need to have well behaving `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods and that objects have those by default.  Some objects choose to remove them to avoid confusing situations.  Where does *immutability* come in to this?

So far, our world consists of being able to store things in a table and look them up *solely* by the object's `id()`.  That's super useful sometimes, but it's still *really* restrictive.  I wouldn't be able to use integers in a lookup table naturally if all I can rely on is their `id()` (what if I store it using a literal but then do a lookup using the result of a computation?).  Fortunately, we live in a world that lets us get around that problem -- *immutability* aids in the construction of a `hash()` value that *isn't* tied to the object's `id()` and isn't in danger of changing during the object's lifetime.  This can be super useful because now I can do:

```
d = {(1, 2, 3): 4}
d[(1, 2) + (3,)] # 4!
```

Now the two tuples that I used were not the same tuple (they didn't have the same `id()`), but they are *equal* and because they're immutable, we can construct a `hash()` function that uses the contents of the `tuple` rather than it's `id()`.  This is super useful!  Note that if the tuple was mutable and we tried to play this trick, we'd (potentially) violate the condition that `hash()` should not change over the lifetime of the object.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Consistent here means that if two objects are *equal*, then they also must have the same hash.  This is necessary for resolving hash collisions which I won't discuss here in detail...</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am confused before these two concepts of immutable and hash.  Thank you for solving my doubts。